# can't find gen_range method on rand::thread_rng

Tags: rust

I'm stuck on the first example given in the Rust book, the guessing game.  I just cannot find the `gen_range` method on `thread_rng()` to generate the number. The only methods that show up are `fill_bytes`, `next_u32`, `next_u64` and `try_fill_bytes`, and if I try to write it anyway I get an error saying the method doesn't exist. However, when I tried the random function, which according to the documentation is simply a shortcut for `thread_rng().gen()`, it works. I've tried other functions, updating and reinstalling everything but it still doesn't work and I really don't know what to do.

Comment: You need to import the trait that defines thread_rng() - add `use rand::Rng;` at the top

Answer (score 13):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, please try to add more information to your question, including relevant links (which doc are you talking about), source code and error messages. This will make it easier for us to give relevant and useful answers.

I'm assuming you're doing something like this:

```
use rand::thread_rng;

fn main() {
    let x = thread_rng().gen_range(0, 10);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=80b97e298bc3606b33bef390995f47f5)

Which gives the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `gen_range` found for struct `rand::rngs::thread::ThreadRng` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:4:26
    |
4   |     let x = thread_rng().gen_range(0, 10);
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `rand::rngs::thread::ThreadRng`
    | 
   ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rand-0.7.3/src/lib.rs:212:8
    |
212 |     fn gen_range<T: SampleUniform, B1, B2>(&mut self, low: B1, high: B2) -> T
    |        ---------
    |        |
    |        the method is available for `std::boxed::Box<rand::rngs::thread::ThreadRng>` here
    |        the method is available for `std::sync::Arc<rand::rngs::thread::ThreadRng>` here
    |        the method is available for `std::rc::Rc<rand::rngs::thread::ThreadRng>` here
    |
    = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
    |
1   | use rand::Rng;
    |
```

Note that the Rust compiler is very good in giving suggestions for ways to fix your code. In this case, the last line from the error suggests adding `use rand::Rng;`, and now it works:

```
use rand::Rng;
use rand::thread_rng;

fn main() {
    let x = thread_rng().gen_range(0, 10);
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4813c9cd820eeffb33c22d69b3b7d526)

This is because the [`gen_range`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range) method is not implemented directly on the [`ThreadRng`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/rngs/struct.ThreadRng.html) struct, but instead it is implemented in the general [`Rng`](https://rust-random.github.io/rand/rand/trait.Rng.html) trait, which makes it automatically available for all random number generators. However methods from traits are only available if the trait itself is available, hence the need to import `rand::Rng` first.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, it works now, and sorry for the lack of information. The docs i was talking about was this one https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/fn.random.html. I have to admit it was my fault for not even trying to run the code, the errors i was talking about were the red lines that show up on vscode, but since i'm using RLS's extension i assumed it was correct and didn't even try to run. My bad. Also, the book (https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html) says nothing about this kind of situation up until this point (maybe later?), so i kinda panicked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing the the following version, works for me in this version.

Add this to your `Cargo.toml` dependencies:

```
rand = "0.7.3"
```

Import:

```rust
use rand::Rng;
```

Usage:

```rust
rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0, 10);
```